# How to make a custom keyboard layout be recognized as Latin so I can remove the US default layout?

Tags: keyboard, language, input-source

I have a custom keyboard layout which MacOSX doesn't recognize as Latin, so it doesn't allow me to remove the US default layout.
I'd like to know what would make my layout be recognized as Latin.
Is the US default layout stored in a file somewhere? so I can compare it to mine and figure out what to change.
My layout is a modified US-international so it should be recognized as Latin with no problems.

Update: I solved it by setting the keyboard id to 1.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this by setting the keyboard id to 1.

[image]

Comment: I changed the id, touched `/Library/Keyboard Layouts/`, and restarted, but still can't disable the U.S layout. I've set my custom layout as the default by running `sudo "/System/Library/CoreServices/Setup Assistant.app/Contents/MacOS/Setup Assistant"`. I tried enabling other input methods as well... Do you have a physical keyboard with a Chinese layout or something?

Comment: @Lri Setting the id to 1 also did not work for me, I tried User/Library, Library, and System/Library.

Comment: @Lri @Tom Sorry to hear it didn't work for you. I just set the id to 1 and worked, when I selected the U.S. keyboard, it wasn't greyed out anymore, so I took it out. I just used `~/Library`. It doesn't work perfectly, as the keyboard turns to chinese whenever I have to enter the admin password, and I cannot change it. (it's ok, since I just type it and hit enter instead of space and it outputs in Roman letters).  
I just have a plain physical U.S. keyboard.

Comment: Din't worked for me as well. I'm running 10.11.4

Comment: @sergei: maybe Apple managed to break it again for 10.11, I'm not using this anymore so not sure if it would still work.

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer first: I haven't tried this myself.

In the message from user `biovizier` at 05-07-2007 10:44 PM in the MacWorld forum thread: http://hintsforums.macworld.com/archive/index.php/t-71629.html , it is claimed that it is possible if it matched both the ID **and** the name of an existing "approved" layout, and that the cache should be cleared to remove the old, compiled version of a such.

However, the thread is quite old so it may have been tightened even further in newer versions.

Answer (score 1):

I think to do what you want you would probably have to modify what is in AppleKeyboardLayouts.bundle, and I haven't seen a way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

There are several different layouts you can use and install from The University of Chicago Library page:

- http://www.lib.uchicago.edu/e/su/mideast/encyclopedia/alt-latin.html

Handy Unicode utilities tools listed here:

- http://www.alanwood.net/unicode/utilities.html#osx

And, you can also customize your layout **System Preferences** > **Language & Text** > **Text**:

[image]