# OS X autoswitch the input method

Tags: macos, input-source

So, I have a really weird problem with OS X 10.8.2. When I last configured it from scratch for the last time (the release of Mountain Lion), I was using the Apple keyboard. So, the default input method is the Belgian one.

But since, I bought another keyboard (Corsair K60). And as the keyboard layout is a bit different from classic Apple layout, I made my own with Ukelele.

It's been working really well since, I think, the last extra update pour 10.8.2. Since then, every time I switch to an app where you mainly type text (Notes, Sparrow, Twitter client, ... But not with Messages weirdly), OS X switch the input method to Belgian. And I can't switch back to my custom one.

I've already checked I've selected the option : "Use the same input method for all documents" is activated. So, I'm a bit stuck here. Any help ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the custom keyboard layout is in `~/Library/Keyboard Layouts/`, have you tried moving it to `/Library/Keyboard Layouts/`? That would normally prevent it from being switched to a default layout in password dialogs.

If you don't need the Belgian layout, there's also a hacky way to [disable the default layouts](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/44921/how-to-remove-or-disable-a-default-keyboard-layout).

Comment: Moving it to `/Library/Keyboard Layouts/` seems to have solve the problem, thank you :)