# PC keyboard inccorect mapping

Tags: keyboard

I've recently been forced to work on a mac book for work. Since I'm a dev I bring my own keyboard rather than just using the macbook one, I had no problem with plugin my keyboard but the mapping are still those of a mac keyboard ( I'm using a french layout ).

A short example to make myself clear, when I press the key labelled 8 / _ on my keyboard the input is ! which is the mac binding on not my keyboard binding.

Is there any simple way to have a standard pc keyboard working on a mac the same way it work on a PC ( I'm not talking about inverting command and control key, just mapping as the keys are labelled )

Thanks in advance

Some refs : 
- Keyboard -> 7G steelseries
- Layout -> Standard french AZERTY layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can consider switching to the U.S layout, it's identical on Mac and Windows in terms of the positions of ASCII characters.

I don't know if there's a premade French PC layout, but you can also use [Ukelele](http://scripts.sil.org/ukelele) to create your own one:

- Select File > New From Current Input Source
- Change the keys
- Save as bundle to `/Library/Keyboard Layouts/` (the popovers shown when holding keys don't work with normal .keylayout files, and keyboard layouts in `~/Library/Keyboard Layouts/` can't be selected in password dialogs or the login window)
- Log out and back in and enable the input source in System Preferences > Language & Text > Input Sources

To apply changes to a keylayout, you have to run `sudo touch /Library/Keyboard Layouts/` (or modify the folder some other way) and log out and back in. You can disable the default French input source by [editing the com.apple.HIToolbox plist](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/60521/3936).

Another option would be to use [KeyRemap4MacBook](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/):

[image]

You can customize the setting group by copying it from [the source](https://github.com/tekezo/KeyRemap4MacBook/blob/master/src/core/server/Resources/include/checkbox/languages/french.xml) to [private.xml](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en).