# How to avoid á é í ó ?

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard

I would like my [a,o,i,e] to appear correctly if I type the letter after an '. 
Right now, I get an accent character as shown in the subject. Is there any way to turn this off?

Comment: If you use a keyboard layout like German or Swedish, you can use Ukelele to replace dead keys like ' with normal keys. See [this question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/97538/how-to-always-insert-single-and-double-quotes/97552#97552).

Comment: The German and Swedish keyboards do Not use ' as a dead key.  They use an acute diacritic character which has no common use, so the problem doesn't arise.  It's US International PC which makes dual use of apostrophe.

Comment: @TomGewecke You're right. The Slovak and Latvian keyboard layouts also use `'` as a dead key though.

Comment: Slovak and Latvian also have ' on keys which are not dead keys, so perhaps using it on the dead keys is an error by apple.

Answer (score 4):

Go to system preferences/language & text/input sources and check the box for US and uncheck the box for US International PC.