# OS X 10.9: Deleting Keyboard Input Sources

Tags: macos, keyboard, preferences, input-source

This is really similar to:
[How to remove or disable a default keyboard layout?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/44921/how-to-remove-or-disable-a-default-keyboard-layout/)
However, I am new here and have no ability to comment or make remarks towards this to voice further problems.

In OS X 10.9, I need to remove input sources in System Preferences > Language and Region > Keyboard Preferences > Input Source.

To be clear, I want these gone completely; if I were to click the add button then I want there to be nothing but the basic English layout available.

---

**Edit:
The solution can be as dangerous as editing near-/root-level files in the OS as long as there's a possible solutions

If no possible solution can be found can anyone recommend third-party software or a way to lock system preferences?**

Answer (score 4):

If others got here searching for how to disable all input sources except a custom keyboard layout, you can edit the `com.apple.HIToolbox` plist:

1. Change the current input source to your custom keyboard layout.
2. Open `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.HIToolbox.plist` (in 10.9) or `~/Library/Preferences/ByHost/com.apple.HIToolbox.*.plist` (in 10.8 and earlier). You can convert the plist to XML with `plutil -convert xml1`.
3. Remove the input source or input sources you want to disable from the `AppleEnabledInputSources` dictionary. If there is an `AppleDefaultAsciiInputSource` key, remove it.
4. Restart.

Comment: if you have Xcode installed, you can directly `open ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.HIToolbox.plist` (in 10.9) from a terminal konsole. The items I had to remove to get rid of the keyboard layouts are those with `InputSourceKind` equal to `Keyboard Layout`

Comment: Again, I'm pretty sure this is not removing the keyboard from the list that you can find in "Keyboard Preferences", "Input Sources", and then the "+" button.

Comment: This solution didn't work for me and seems a bit risky.

Comment: new versions of OS X (12.2) seem to automatically re-add the deleted input source

Answer (score 1):

I not completely sure that's what you're looking for. But if you want to remove some input sources. You just have to select them then click the "minus" button.

You can delete them all but one. There has to be a least one input source. In your case one of the english input sources.

[image]

Edit : OP want's to remove all the input source from the list (accessible by clicking the "+" button). And that's not possible.

Comment: From @user61808 : No this does not delete the input sources. This just removes them from the list but they can still be re-added via the plus button. They need to be deleted, not hidden.

Comment: In that case can anyone think of any third party options for locking system preferences? Thusly, does anyone know the root of the input sources to where I could simply delete them (I understand this would be os/root level and is dangerous).

Comment: System preferences > Security & Privacy > Advanced > Require password to access system wide preferences.

Answer (score 1):

For Sonoma 14.3 the correct answer is:

1. Lock the screen by using the Apple menu or hitting <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>Q</kbd>
2. On the lock screen, click on the keyboard icon in the upper right corner to select the (standard) layout you want to remove
3. Click the keyboard icon again to select `Remove Current Input Source`

Now in the list of input sources in the keyboard system settings, there's only the custom layout left.
There you could also re-add a standard layout and the button to remove it would be grayed out again.

copied from https://superuser.com/a/1825176/1885119 by https://superuser.com/users/1279444/imawizard, original answer by https://superuser.com/users/417468/thorstenhirsch

Answer (score 0):

*[edit: Disregard this answer - it addresses custom keyboard layouts which you can remove by deleting them from the "Keyboard Layouts" dir. Op wanted an answer for default Apple languages preinstalled in the system]*

The easiest way to remove a custom keyboard layout from "Input Sources -> +" list (when clicking the add button) is to use [Keyboard Juggler](https://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=ukelele) (see section "Companion Application").

> Keyboard Juggler is a simple app designed to simplify the work flow of
>   editing keyboard layouts. It simply gives you a way to move keyboard
>   layouts in and out of the folders that macOS uses for enabling the use
>   of keyboard layouts, without having to use the Finder or show hidden
>   folders. It is intended as a companion application to Ukelele, the
>   keyboard layout editor.

So simple yet so effective - 3 clicks and the layouts are gone.

[image]

Comment: The question is how to remove Apple's input sources.  Removing custom layouts is not a problem even without keyboard juggler.

Comment: @TomGewecke ahh I didn't get the Apple part. So how do you remove the custom ones without keyboard juggler?

Comment: You just manually drag the .keylayout or .bundle files out of the Keyboard Layouts folder.

Comment: Thanks. I added a comment that my answer is invalid so it's clear that I address a different issue.